# Why Karma is not running specific component tests only?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular-unit-test

I have an Angular app in which i have many components. But for now I just want to run the tests for `login.component.ts` so for that I did in my `test.ts` file like this

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /login\.component\.spec\.ts$/);
```

But when I run `ng test` it runs all components' test files and gives an error on one of the directives I have like this:

[image]

Comment: Why edit the test.ts file? Pass the --include argument to the test command (see https://angular.io/cli/test) or use fdescribe to focus your tests.

Comment: Also are you sure it's running all of the tests? I think it's just trying to compile your code before running the tests, if you fix the basic compilation errors does it run all of them?

Comment: can you give any example of --include command as referenced to login component?

Comment: What is unclear from the docs? `--include path/to/login.component.ts`?

Comment: I tried `ng test --include ./src/app/modules/app-components/login.component.spe.ts` So it is giving an error like `specified pattern did not match any spec files`

Comment: Typo - `.spe.ts`?

Comment: yes that's a typo. I tried with `spec.ts`